# Sharing data between iOs 10 and WatchOS 3 (Shared Container)

Tags: ios, swift, share, apple-watch

I try to program an exercise App for the Apple Watch and iPhone.
However, I'm not able to send my multidimensional Array to my iPhone.
I tried many suggestions like the [WCsession](https://www.raywenderlich.com/117329/watchos-2-tutorial-part-4-watch-connectivity), [NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750088/swift-does-not-conform-to-protocol-nscoding) or CoreData using a [shared container](https://swifting.io/blog/2016/09/25/25-core-data-in-ios10-nspersistentcontainer/?utm_source=swifting.io&utm_medium=web&utm_campaign=blog%20post).

There are some solutions already suggested here on stackoverflow but often they only send a short String or dictionary.

**My App:**

I have two classes with my variables:

```
class WorkoutClass: NSObject {
var date: String
var exercise: String
var duration: Double
var repetitions: Double?
var meanRepDuration: Double?
var idealAngle: Double?
var meanAngle: Double?
var repArray: Array<Any>?


init(date: String, exercise: String, duration: Double, repetitions: Double?, meanRepDuration: Double?, idealAngle: Double?, meanAngle: Double?, repArray: Array<Any>?) {


    self.date = date
    self.exercise = exercise
    self.duration = duration
    self.repetitions = repetitions
    self.meanRepDuration = meanRepDuration
    self.idealAngle = idealAngle
    self.meanAngle = meanAngle
    self.repArray = repArray

}
}
```

and

```
class RepetitionClass: NSObject { 
var oneRepAngle: Double?
    var oneRepStartTime: Double?
    var oneRepEndTime: Double?
    var oneRepInternalVariation: Double?

init(oneRepAngle: Double?, oneRepStartTime: Double?, oneRepEndTime: Double?, oneRepInternalVariation: Double?) {

        self.oneRepAngle = oneRepAngle
        self.oneRepStartTime = oneRepStartTime
        self.oneRepEndTime = oneRepEndTime
        self.oneRepInternalVariation = oneRepInternalVariation

    }
    }
```

*Annotation: Because I get my data in a special way i had to do it like this. For each exercise an array is added with specific data from each repetition*

This will be added together with multiple exercises into an array called "exerciseArray":

I get my acceleration data from the Watch and store it into an array. 
This array is declared as:

```
var exerciseArray = [Any]()
```

But putting this array into a dictionary and send it with userDefaults did not work. I was also suggested to cast my exerciseArray into Data and send it with `sendMessage`. Unfortunately, all tutorials found on youtube, stackoverflow or anywhere else did not work for iOS 10 and watchOS 3.

Therefore, if someone could suggest a method to share data (not only small data/dictionaries) between an iOS app and its extension that would actually help a lot of other people too (as I already saw here on stackoverflow).

I would prefer using a shared container with Core Data but since I'm totally new in programming I ask you for your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since WatchOS2 you are no longer to share Core Data, but you can use WatchConnectivity framework to pass the information you need between the phone and the watch.