# iOS How to make a function to accept parameter confirming to NSCoding

Tags: ios, swift, function, swift4, nscoding

I have a function which saves primitives and objects confirming to `NSCoding` to `UserDefaults`.

```
func set(_ value: Any?, forKey key: String) {
    if let value = value {
        if (value is NSCoding) {
            let encodedValue = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: value)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedValue, forKey: key)
        } else {
            print("Storage: failed to save value for key \(key). Value must confirm to NSCoding protocol")
        }
    } else {
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: key)
    }
}
```

I want to get rid of the conformance check inside the function. So the function must accept only `NSCoding` values.

I’ve tried to change the function's signature to this:

```
func set(_ value: NSCoding?, forKey key: String)
```

And this:

```
func set<T: Any>(_ value: T?, forKey key: String) where T: NSCoding
```

However, I get a compile error in every function call.

In the first case I get:

> Argument type ‘***’ does not conform to expected type 'NSCoding?'

In the second:

> Cannot convert value of type '***' to expected argument type '_?'

What should I change to make it work?

Comment: That first attempt seems right. The error makes it clear that you are trying to pass a value that doesn’t conform to NSCoding. You can’t do that once you change the parameter from Any to NSCoding.

Comment: I don't understand why `Int` value doesn't confirm to `NSCoding` but passes check inside function `if (value is NSCoding)`

Comment: The archive method you're calling doesn't require NSCoding so why do you need it?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure. I'm working with legacy obj-c code which had check for `encodeWithCoder` selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems no issue in method declaration itself

```
func set<T: Any>(_ value: T?, forKey key: String) where T: NSCoding {
    if let value = value {
            let encodedValue = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: value)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedValue, forKey: key)
    } else {
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: key)
    }
}
```

But the compilation error points out that the value you are passing to this function might not be compatible with `NSCoding`

example calling the above function with

```
self.set("abcd", forKey: "test")
```

Gives error

> Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '_?'

On the other hand calling it as

```
self.set(NSString(string: "abcd"), forKey: "test")
```

Works fine. So make sure you pass correct argument :)

**EDIT 1:**

Based on OP's comment tested the Generics method with `Int`

```
    let test: Int = 100
    self.set(test, forKey: "test")
```

Results in same error, boxing it to NSNumber though

```
    let test: Int = 100
    self.set(NSNumber(value: test), forKey: "test")
```

**EDIT 2:**

Answering OP's comment

> But why String values pass if (value is NSCoding) check in my original
>   function?

```
    let a: Any = "abcd"
    if a is NSCoding {
        debugPrint("am here")
    }
```

Thats because your any passes the `NSCoding` check and in your case no matter what value you pass to function you type cast it to `Any` and `Any` passes through the check :)

Hence its working in your first method but fails with generics :) 
Hope it helps

Comment: So `String` doesn't confirm to `NSCoding`?

Comment: Yes. Swift data types does not confirm to NSCoding directly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750088/swift-does-not-conform-to-protocol-nscoding

Comment: But why `String` values pass `if (value is NSCoding)` check in my original function?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can skip `NSCoding` all together?

```
func set(_ value: Any?, forKey key: String) throws {
    if let value = value {
        let encodedValue = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: value, requiringSecureCoding: true)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedValue, forKey: key)
    } else {
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: key)
    }
}
```

(Note that I change to non-deprecated method but feel free to change back)

Example

```
do { 
    try set("abc", forKey: "k1")
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```